# Custom projection on view makes tiles scrambled

Tags: openlayers, projection

When i change the view projection to SWEREF99 the tiles in a tilelayer are scrambled.

[image: Scarambled tiles]

I haven't seen any information that it should de impossible to use a custom projection on the view.

If I don't use tiles, then it seems to work, but tiles are good!

Parts of my code below:

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center: [6744417, 522087],
    zoom: 9,
    projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:3006',
        units: 'm'
    })
});
```

and

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    name: 'Name',
    visible: false,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
        url: 'http://xxx:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'yyyy' },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    }))
})
```

Is it possible or not to use custom projection on a ol.view?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143883/openlayers-3-wms-custom-projection-wrong-extent

Comment: What is the projection for the layer in Geoserver?

Comment: The data is stored in SWEREF99 TM (EPSG_3006) and that's what I configured GeoServer to use when published.

Comment: OL itself supports `EPSG:3006` projection? check http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.Projection.html and try proj4

Comment: Well, I both linked in proj4 and projDefs with: 
    <script src="Scripts/proj4/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://epsg.io/3006.js"></script>
and created the projectionobject above. Shouldn't that work!?